# Wrap a UDP POSIX Socket into a TCP CFNetworking (or the like) socket for VOIP usage

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm writing a VOIP client for the iPhone/iPad. The service uses one hole-punched UDP connection to a server, and then a P2P UDP connection to each friend in the friendlist.

The connections are POSIX sockets as far as I know (using the sys/socket.h).

Researching Apple's documentation, they require

1. TCP sockets, UDP stopped working since iOS 4.2
2. Non-POSIX, high-level socketing stuff, like their CFNetworking class

for background VOIP services.

I think it's possible to wrap sockets with CFNetworking, but I have no idea how to do that, nor if it's at all possible to convert it to TCP.

Also I think iOS only allows 1 socket connection for the app in background, does anyone have more info on the validity of that, or if there is a way around it? And of course, does anybody know about wrapping the socket?

Comment: Did you solved it? I'm having a similar issue.